# Passing template class as parameter to class method and using template class as vector template type

Tags: c++

It has been a while since I have used templates with C++, but now I really need them.

I reproduced a problem I am having and I don't remember how the solution actually went.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace problem {
    template <typename T>
    class data {
        public:
            inline data(T var) {
                this->var = var;
            }
        private:
            T var;
    };

    class storage {
        public:
            inline void push(problem::data<T> * data) {
                this->VData.push_back(data);
            }
        private:
            std::vector<problem::data<T> *> VData;
    };
};

int main() {
    problem::storage * testStorage = new problem::storage();
    problem::data<int> * testData = new problem::data<int>(256);

    testStorage->push(testData);

    delete testData;
    delete testStorage;
    return 0;
}
```

g++ -Wall problem.cpp gives me the following errors.

```
problem.cpp:17:35: error: ‘T’ was not declared in this scope
problem.cpp:17:36: error: template argument 1 is invalid
problem.cpp:21:30: error: ‘T’ was not declared in this scope
problem.cpp:21:31: error: template argument 1 is invalid
problem.cpp:21:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
problem.cpp:21:34: error: template argument 2 is invalid
problem.cpp: In member function ‘void problem::storage::push(int*)’:
problem.cpp:18:17: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘((problem::storage*)this)->problem::storage::VData’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
problem.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
problem.cpp:29:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘problem::storage::push(problem::data<int>*&)’
problem.cpp:29:28: note: candidate is:
problem.cpp:17:16: note: void problem::storage::push(int*)
problem.cpp:17:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘problem::data<int>*’ to ‘int*’
```

I know I can use member templates, but what I do with the vector?

```
template <typename T>
inline void push(problem::data<T> * data) {
    this->VData.push_back(data);
}
```

If I use the member template then the vector definition will leave these errors.

```
problem.cpp:22:30: error: ‘T’ was not declared in this scope
problem.cpp:22:31: error: template argument 1 is invalid
problem.cpp:22:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
problem.cpp:22:34: error: template argument 2 is invalid
problem.cpp: In member function ‘void problem::storage::push(problem::data<T>*)’:
problem.cpp:19:17: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘this->.VData’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
```

Comment: Why not make your whole `storage` class a template, too, if you have a data member that depends on it?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, but I would have done it if it would be good idea in my mind. Thing is the actual "storage" class I have will take more than 10 different templates as data members.

`template <typename A, typename B, typename c, typename D, typename E, typename F, typename G, typename H, typename I, typename J, ...>` 

This would not be nice in my mind. :/

Comment: @Ternek all of these complaints have standard solutions, and it is **not** a reinterpret cast!!! See `Boost::Any` (and/or type-erased containers), `template<template <typename T> Container>` and `std::tuple<>` (to work with long lists of data member types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want storage that can store more than one type of value you can try something like this: http://ideone.com/jjuVq

```
class storage {
    struct data_base {};

    template <class K> 
    struct data: data_base {
        data(K value): value_(value) {}
        K value_;
    };

    typedef std::vector<data_base*> container_type;

public:
    ~storage() {
        while(!this->VData.empty()) {
            delete this->VData.back();
            this->VData.pop_back();
        }
    }
    template <class P>
    inline void push(P v) {
        this->VData.push_back(new data<P>(v));
    }
    template <class P>
    P &get(int i) { return static_cast<data<P>*>(this->VData[i])->value_; }
private:
    container_type VData;
};
```

or just use boost::any as a container's value type.

Comment: This is nice, but I actually found a solution already and with less code than this.

Comment: This leaks memory. Please use `std::unique_ptr` to store the data.

Comment: Check the one from the link - I just didn't updated it here. And by the way `std::unique_ptr` is a C++11 thing - it won't work if you are not using `-std=c++11` or equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try to use boost::any?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

namespace problem {
    template <typename T>
    class data {
        public:
            inline data(T var) {
                this->var = var;
            }
        private:
            T var;
    };

    class storage {
        public:
            template<class T>
            inline void push(problem::data<T> * data) {
                this->VData.push_back(data);
            }
        private:
            std::vector<boost::any> VData;
    };
};

int main() {
    problem::storage * testStorage = new problem::storage();
    problem::data<int> * testData = new problem::data<int>(256);

    testStorage->push<int>(testData);

    problem::data<float> * testData1 = new problem::data<float>(1.);
    testStorage->push<float>(testData1);

    delete testData;
    delete testData1;
    delete testStorage;
    return 0;
}
```

But you need to cast from boost::any to your type before using data from vector

Answer (score 1):

Your storage class has a data member that depends on a template parameter, so you should make it a class template:

```
template <typename T>
class storage {
    public:
        inline void push(problem::data<T> * data) {
            this->VData.push_back(data);
        }
    private:
        std::vector<problem::data<T> *> VData;
};
```

Otherwise, you could make `storage` work for a specific type `T`:

```
class storage {
    public:
        inline void push(problem::data<int> * data) {
            this->VData.push_back(data);
        }
    private:
        std::vector<problem::data<int> *> VData;
};
```

Comment: Making storage to be a template would work, but this is just a reproduction of the problem I am having and the storage would require to have several template types to work as a template.

I could use specific type for the storage T, but that would break down when I try to push class template which has T type other than the one used for the storage T.

Comment: @Temek the class needs to be a template if you have a template data member. There's no easy way around that. If it is possible to have an abstract base class that encompasses `data` behaviour, you could have a vector of pointers to that abstract type. But that would only make sense if the `data`s do the same kind of stuff at the public interface level.

Answer (score -3):

I found a solution which is kinda what I was looking for, but I'm not sure if this is good practice. :P

```
class storage {
    public:
        template <typename T>
        inline void push(problem::data<T> * data) {
            this->VData.push_back(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data));
        }
        template <typename T>
        inline problem::data<T> * draw() {
            problem::data<T> * data = reinterpret_cast<problem::data<T>*>(VData.back());
            return data;
        }
    private:
        std::vector<char*> VData;
};
```

Comment: BURN THIS ANSWER. You cannot just cast anything you want. This is UB, and will likely crash before you can say "pumpkins"

Comment: It seems to work fine for now, so i'm good until it breaks if it breaks.

Comment: @Temek undefined behaviour is undefined regardless of what it looks like it's doing now. There's a good reason people advocate avoiding C-style casts in C++.

Comment: Now it is not using C style casting, but reinterpret_cast so it's not undefined behavior anymore.

Comment: @Temek what you are doing is equivalent to ramming a car down a birds through whilst shouting that it's a tasty little worm! You can not just magically convert types like this

Comment: @Ternek: this will work **until** you actually call push or draw for mismatched type. I admit I have misread your code earlier. Given the right conditions and usage patterns, this might work, but it will never be safe. Nor sane. Boost::any is the solution for this